# JAX-RS spec vs Swagger Spec difference

Tags: rest, swagger, jax-rs, openapi, swagger-ui

I'm confused which came first JAX-RS Or Swagger Spec and their differences. Both have implementation. I seen spring boot Rest Api which implementation this uses? Sorry new to development and can't find any information related to this.

Trying to understand the basics and searched other questions. Expecting someone to clarify the fundamental differences between Jax-rs and swagger spec (now called OpenApi spec I think)